# Restart in spring batch without using job repository

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am new to spring batch and trying to design a spring batch job which uses a text file as mechanism to skip records before starting the job.If the string in text file is greater than 0 which represents the committed records(lets say n), I should skip first n records in reader and start from n+1.What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can have a simple with a single step
2. Have a listener at Step level.
3. In BeforeStep event, you read the file to store a value into StepExecutionContext with a key "skipParam"
4. Using that stepExecutionContext['skipParam'] in FlatFileItemReader

If you don't know how to implement above steps in detail, let me know. I will post an example for you.

Comment: Hi Can you please post an example of how to retrieve the context in flat file reader and jump to that line?

Comment: Please see the link https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/11/21/using-linestoskip-dynamically-from-flatfileitemreader/